# How to find the second highest score only using loop (no array)

Tags: java, loops

So basically I have to find the students with the highest and second highest score ONLY using loop (no array).

My code is

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner myScanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        int k,max1, max2, grade,count,number;
        String student,grades;
        number= myScanner.nextInt();
        myScanner.nextLine();
        student= myScanner.nextLine();
        k= student.indexOf(' ');
        grades= student.substring(k+1);
        grade= Integer.parseInt(grades);
        count=0;
        max1= grade;
        max2= 0;

        while(count<number){
            student= myScanner.nextLine();
            k= student.indexOf(' ');
            grades= student.substring(k+1);
            grade= Integer.parseInt(grades);
            count++;
            if(grade==max1){
                max1= grade;
                max2= grade;
            }
            else if(grade>max1){
                max2= max1;
                max1= grade;
            }
            if(student.contains(max1+""))
                System.out.println(student);
            if(student.contains(max2+""))
                System.out.println(student);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that my problem is the 'student' is just temporary and because of that I can't print it out at the end. How should I solve this?

Comment: Welcome Cherry hill St. ! Please share your input and expected output as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the maximum grades, you can store the `student` with the maximum grades, because you can easily find the grade value if you have the `student` string with you.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner myScanner= new Scanner(System.in);
        int k,grade,count,number;
        String student,grades,maxStudent1,maxStudent2;
        number= myScanner.nextInt();
        myScanner.nextLine();
        student= myScanner.nextLine();

        count=0;
        maxStudent1= student;

        while(count<number){
            student= myScanner.nextLine();

            grade= getGrade(student);
            count++;
            if(grade >= getGrade(maxStudent1)) {
                maxStudent2= maxStudent1;
                maxStudent1= student;
            }
            else if(grade > getGrade(maxStudent2)) {
                maxStudent2= student;
            }
            if(student.equals(maxStudent1))
                System.out.println(student);
            if(student.equals(maxStudent2))
                System.out.println(student);
        }
    }

    private int getGrade(String student) {
        if(student == null) {
            return 0; 
        }
        int k = student.indexOf(' ');
        if(k==-1) {
            return 0;
        }
        String grades= student.substring(k+1);
        return Integer.parseInt(grades);
    }
}
```

Also, the logic to find the maximum and second maximum grade has been updated since your logic was incorrect. Example, for input: `[10, 15, 12]`, your code would have `max1: 15` and `max2: 10`, while correct `max2: 12`.

Alternatively, instead of parsing the grades from the `student` string everytime, you could have two extra strings `maxStudent1` and `maxStudent2` along with the `max1` and `max2` grades corresponding to these grades so as to remove the parsing of string in every comparision.